# Recording a stethoscope

Tags: sound-design, field-recording, sound-effects-recording, experimental, human

Anyone know a good, inexpensive way to record the sounds off of a stethoscope? I'd like to get some recordings of the inside of the body.

Comment: I downvoted because you have not enough information on what you already tried. Nor is there information about your setup/gear.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what type of gear you already have.
But check out [this](http://boingboing.net/2011/03/15/diego-stocco-plays-a.html) video with Diego Stocco.
He uses a stethoscope and I think he inserted a lavalier microphone in the tube.
Not sure, but worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Some weeks ago I put an inexpensive electret capsule inside the tube of a stethoscope and recorded my stomach and my heartbeat. I paid about 2euros for the capsule and the recordings turned out to be pretty usuable.